# Progress bar showing wrong values in Android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have android app in which I have a part like this:

```
NavigationDrawer -> Fragment A (shown below) -> Fragment B
```

`Fragment A` is like a list, in which clicking on an item opens `Fragment B` which shows its details.
My problem is that when I go back from `Fragment B` to `Fragment A`, the `ProgressBar` of all items of list show wrong values, even when tried to change the orientation.
It only shows correct value when opened from `NavigationDrawer`.
I am a lot confused and clueless since other fields of item do show correct values.

As an observation, progress of each `ProgressBar` is set to the progress of last item in the list.

`Fragment A`

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.contents_grades_sem_wise.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.grades_sem_wise_row.view.*
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

class FragmentGradesSemWise : Fragment(), DialogGPAAddGroup.GPAAddGroupListener {

    private val myCGPA = RecordOfCGPA()
    private class RecordOfCGPA {
        var cgpa = 0f
        var credits = 0
        var previousDone = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contents_grades_sem_wise, container, false)
        activity!!.title = "Grades"

        val gpaPrefs = activity!!.getSharedPreferences("GPA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val gpaSet = HashSet(gpaPrefs.getStringSet("semesters", HashSet()))

        val rootView = theView.gsw_root
        rootView.addView(setHeader(inflater, container))

        myCGPA.cgpa = 0f            // I have re-initialised these variables here
        myCGPA.credits = 0          // because otherwise they result in wrong calculation
        myCGPA.previousDone = true  // which I think was somehow related to my strange problem
        for (sem in gpaSet.sorted()) {
            val gpaModelString = gpaPrefs.getString(sem, "")
            val modelGPA = Gson().fromJson(gpaModelString, ModelGPA::class.java)
            rootView.addView(setViewGPA(modelGPA, inflater, container))
        }
        return theView
    }

    private fun setHeader(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): View {
        val hView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grades_sem_wise_row, container, false)

        hView.gswr_sno.text = "Semester"
        hView.gswr_sno.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
        hView.gswr_tc.text = "Credits"
        hView.gswr_tc.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
        hView.gswr_sgpa.text = "SGPA"
        hView.gswr_sgpa.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
        hView.gswr_cgpa.text = "CGPA"
        hView.gswr_cgpa.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
        hView.gswr_pbv.visibility = View.GONE

        hView.gswr_root.isClickable = false
        hView.gswr_root.isFocusable = false
        hView.gswr_root.isLongClickable = false

        return hView
    }

    private fun setViewGPA(modelGPA: ModelGPA, inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): View {
        val mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grades_sem_wise_row, container, false)
        mView.tag = modelGPA.sem

        mView.gswr_sno.text = modelGPA.sem.toString()

        var credits = 0
        var gradeSum = 0
        var gradedCredits = 0
        var possibleGrades = 0

        for (sub in modelGPA.list) {
            credits += sub.credits
            if (sub.grade == null) {
                possibleGrades += sub.credits * 10
            } else {
                possibleGrades += sub.credits * sub.grade!!
                gradeSum += sub.credits * sub.grade!!
                gradedCredits += sub.credits
            }
        }

        mView.gswr_tc.text = credits.toString()
        if (credits != 0) {
            if (gradedCredits == credits) {
                val sgpa = gradeSum.toFloat() / credits
                mView.gswr_sgpa.text = String.format("%.2f", sgpa)
                if (myCGPA.previousDone) {
                    myCGPA.cgpa = ((myCGPA.cgpa * myCGPA.credits) + gradeSum) / (myCGPA.credits + gradedCredits)
                    myCGPA.credits += gradedCredits
                    mView.gswr_cgpa.text = String.format("%.2f", myCGPA.cgpa)
                }
            } else myCGPA.previousDone = false
/*here is*/ mView.gswr_pbv.progress = if (gradedCredits != 0) 10 * gradeSum / gradedCredits else 0
/*progress*/mView.gswr_pbv.secondaryProgress = 10 * possibleGrades / credits
/*bar*/ } else myCGPA.previousDone = false

        mView.setOnClickListener {
            if (actionMode == null) {
                listener.showGPADetails(modelGPA.sem)
            } else {
                myTracker.toggle(modelGPA.sem)
            }
        }
        mView.setOnLongClickListener {
            myTracker.toggle(modelGPA.sem)
            true
        }

        return mView
    }

}
```

`grades_sem_wise_row.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gswr_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gswr_sno"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gswr_tc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gswr_sgpa"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gswr_cgpa"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/gswr_pbv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/gswr_sel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

`content_grades_sem_wise.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gsw_root"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- layouts added from code -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The values I am setting to `ProgressBar` do show correct values in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what is the problem, but as I said everything is OK when I open `Fragment A` from `NavigationDrawer`, so what I did is when I press back button from `Fragment B`, I have set a listener for the event as follows:

`Fragment B`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    view.requestFocus()
    view.setOnKeyListener { _, _, event ->
        if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            listener.onBackPressedFromGradesDetails()
            true
        } else false
    }
}
```

and handling orientation change in `Fragment A` as follows:

`Fragment A`

```
override fun onCreateView(//...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) listener.onRotationOfGPA()
```

and handled both the listeners in the `MainActivity` to start `Fragment A` anew.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a lifecycle problem, but I'm not 100% certain because it's hard to tell how you're performing the fragment transactions without seeing the code.

Your code calls `setViewGPA(...)` *during* `onCreateView(...)`, I would refactor that more into `onViewCreated(...)` for example, to ensure the code gets executed after the views have been created.

Add Logging in your lifecycle methods (not breakpoints) and observe the order in which things get called, chances are the calculation you want to perform is not happening when you think it is.

Either that, or you're not popping the right fragments, I can't say for sure without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I have tried to put calculation of `setViewGPA(...` in `onCreateView(...)`, that didn't help. The `listener` I have set on `onClickListener{..` is in the `MainActivity`, and this is how I am doing the transaction: `supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_main, theFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()`.

Comment: You're going to need to debug a little bit further, it's impossible to tell what your application is doing without having access to it. Think of this as a simple issue, so if it's not displaying the correct form, ask yourself: What is it displayign? What happens if I make it display an arbitrary hardcoded value, does it show that? What if I change said value in `onResume`? What if I do it in `onStart` does it overwrite the other value? Debug your app step by step, add logging, try to determine who/when is setting things. That's the process I would do.